# Formula for Integral over disk

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $r >0$ such that $|x|=|(x_1,x_2)|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}>r.$ Can we find a formula depending on $x,r$ of $$\int_{B(x,r)}\frac{1}{|y|^{\frac{1}{2}}}dy?$$

Could we bound the integral by $A+B|x|$, for some $A,B>0$? I know how to bound it by $r^{\frac{7}{4}}$, but it does not help me a lot.

Comment: Is $|y|$ the norm of the generic element of the ball $B(x,r)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is the distance from the origin

Comment: How explicit do you want this formula? I can get one in terms of an integral of a hypergeometric function and I doubt you will be able to get anything more explicit

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your application you may just want to  estimate the integral

Comment: Yes, I included the estimate that I would need in the statement of the question